# VSCode Remote - Use other name for devcontainer.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I am working in VSCode from a git project where there is already a devcontainer/devcontainer.json, which is a devcontainer the dev team uses (it is tracked by git).
Now I want to have my own devcontainer for my own tests, that I will not track in git but that I need to keep in the same workspace. I was hoping that I could configure the remote extension to use another container configuration for instance .devcontainer/local_devcontainer.json, but I don't find how to do so.
Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/connect-multiple-containers